# How to run a WP7 silverlight application after some period of time?

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, timer

I have an application in WP7 silverlight that needs to be launched after a specific period of time, something like an alarm.

But I want to launch the application itself not WP7's alarm.

I use:

this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

for hiding the application, I know it is not the correct way for making it run in the background.

Any hint please? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into Background Agents : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202941(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The platform specifically does not support running apps in the way you describe.

If your functionality can't run in a background agent then your only options are to use an alarm or toast message (sent as a push notification) to prompt the user to start the app.

One of the design decisions behind the platform is that the user should always know what is going on on the phone so having apps stop and start by themselves would be contrary to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a background agent and display a toast notification to the user , and launch the application when the user clicks on the toast.

You can also push toast messages to the device, and rely on the user clicking the toast .